# What are the files and folder I should automatically exclude?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

I have a Visual Studio 2010 project with Unit Test project.

We have 5 peoples working in a team.

I am using SVN and TortoiseSVN client for source control.

What are the files and folder I should automatically exclude from the soruce control?

Below is the folder I am excluding:

1. bin
2. obj

Should I exclude files like sln, suo, csproj, and TestResults?

Thank you.

---

Edited:

I think below is the list:

global-ignores = bin obj *.suo *.obj *.pdb *.exe *.dll *.csproj.user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sln is the solution file, so no, you do not want to exclude this.

Suo should be excluded, as this is user defined Visual Studio settings.

CsProj is the project file for one of the projects within your solution, so again no, do not exclude this.

TestResults are used by Visual Studio's Test Runner, so you will want to exclude this.

You may also want to exclude any Resharper settings file, if you use Resharper.

If you use Stylecop and want shared StyleCop settings, make sure the stylecop files are in there.

If you have any third party libraries, make sure they are in one place.